# Automatic login when already logged in to SE Facebook, etc

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

When I am logged in to one of the sites that you can use to login to SE or SO, and I go into SE or SO, I suggest it automatically logs you in or ask if you want to be automatically login with that account or select an alternative.

Right now, you have to hit login, directing you to another page with all the options, and then you have to select the one you are already logged into. Why be directed to this page when you can just ask from the home page of SO or SE if you want the above two possible options ( now or for now on )?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is very hard or impossible to implement due to the nature of OpenID. You are logged out of SE so SE have no way of knowing who you are: they have no previous session cookie from you so they cannot just send an id over to the correct provider to see if you are logged in.

They would need to redirect your browser to *all* login providers since it is the login provider that checks if you are logged in. This is of course not feasible since no user wants to wade through ten different login screens of which they *may* be logged in to *one* provider.